# How to select an answer from options in command line(terminal) using python.?

Tags: javascript, python, command-line, command-line-interface, eslint

I am trying to access command line form python code. here is two example where I got stuck. In this code, there is a question and 3 or 4 options to select as answer. How can I select any of these answer using python code. In real case If I am using it from command line I have to use up and down arrow
`↑  ↓` key or right and left arrow `<  >` key then enter key to select any one of the options.

```
*example:1>*

? How would you like to use ESLint? … 
  To check syntax only
▸ To check syntax and find problems
  To check syntax, find problems, and enforce code style

*example:2>*

✔ How would you like to use ESLint? · problems
? What type of modules does your project use? … 
▸ JavaScript modules (import/export)
  CommonJS (require/exports)
  None of these
```

Normally, I have to answer it by selecting answer from list and pressing enter from terminal, is there any possibility to answer these  questions by using python code?

---

**Here I am describing my use case.**

I am trying to create automate `ESLint` vulnerability check for TypeScript files using python.

I am able to run `ESLint --init` to initialise ESLint in my project. While initializing  `ESLint --init` is asking some questions to specify the type of project. Some of the questions are following:

```
*example:1>*

? How would you like to use ESLint? … 
  To check syntax only
▸ To check syntax and find problems
  To check syntax, find problems, and enforce code style

*example:2>*

✔ How would you like to use ESLint? · problems
? What type of modules does your project use? … 
▸ JavaScript modules (import/export)
  CommonJS (require/exports)
  None of these
```

Normally, I have to answer it by selecting answer from list and pressing enter from terminal, is there any possibility to answer these  questions by using python code?

following code was used to run `eslint --init` from python code:

```
def eslint_init():
    if pathlib.Path('.eslintrc.js').exists():
        print('already initialized')
    else:
        os.system('eslint --init')
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with `javascript`?

Comment: @Andreas : ESLint is A pluggable and configurable linter tool for identifying and reporting on patterns in JavaScript.

Comment: _"is there any possibility to automate this answering questions by using python code?"_ - The question is about automation with a python script. What the tool does that you're trying to automate (its initialization to be more precise) is not relevant for the question.

Comment: @Andreas Thankyou  you are right. Yeah I see, I will edit the question. I want to answer those questions from python it self. that is what I meant.